# Stop setInterval when video is paused (Youtube player)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, setinterval

I have some difficulty with this problem. I use youtube api to integrate video on my website.

To control the time, i need to use setInterval function to get the current time.The setInterval is polling every 100 ms.
The only problem, if you pause, or stop the video, the setInterval continue to poll every 100ms, he never stop.

I really don't know stop it with the code i have, I see basic example with `clearInterval` but the code is more complicated.
I made a live exemple, play the video, you will see the problem in the output console.

http://jsbin.com/pazamihi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Exemple of the problem :

http://i.gyazo.com/be10ae615d28b8502783975e216fad54.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is not that tricky.
I first added mytimer to the global scope:

```
var mytimer; //declare variable mytimer in global scope for later usage
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
...
```

Within the onPlayerStateChange() function there's an else condition which contains `//Video has paused`.
Replace that line with

```
clearTimeout(mytimer);
```

That works for me.